# How do I extract a string from a class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I extract the string from the following:

```
<div class="lineup__mteam is-home">
                                        Hertha BSC Berlin                                        <span class="lineup__wl"></span>
</div>
```

I use the following code

```
label = soup.find('class', text = 'lineup__mteam is-home')
Team = label.next_sibling.strip()
```

But get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'`

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to find the element by its id or class then access the text property of that element.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="lineup__mteam is-home">
           Hertha BSC Berlin
    <span class="lineup__wl"></span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('div', class_='lineup__mteam').text.strip()
print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
Hertha BSC Berlin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<div class="lineup__mteam is-home">
Hertha BSC Berlin<span class="lineup__wl"></span>
</div>"""

parser = BeautifulSoup(text)
print(parser.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Hertha BSC Berlin
```